# Compare the results of two web services and save the results to a database (preferably SQL server)

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, automated-tests, avalara

There are 2 web services that validate a given address. My task is to compare the results of these two services and save the results to a database (preferably SQL server).

The input is a table with 2 million addresses and schema of the table along with a sample address is as follows:
[image]

I need to Design and code a tool in C# that can perform the task stated above.

**More info:**
*Example Input:*

AddressLine 1 = 700 Pik Street, AddressLine 2 = Avalara, City = Seattle, Region = Washington , PostalCode = 98110

**The webservice takes the input address and returns a validated address as follows:**
AddressLine 1 = 700 Pike St, AddressLine 2 = Avalara, City = Seattle, Region = WA , PostalCode = 98110-2311

Each of the web service can return a slightly different output address. My goal is to find the differences!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Have fun! This site isn't for asking people to do the work for you. This seems fairly straight forward.

Comment: You can hire some developer to do you job. Stack overflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to re-invent the wheel, there are existing tools which can execute web service requests, compare the responses and execute and arbitrary database call.

For example given [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) - free and open source modular load testing tool you can:

1. Execute web service calls via [HTTP Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)
2. Insert the results into the database using  [JDBC PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_PostProcessor)
3. Compare results using [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)

If it sounds promising I would recommend attending free [JMeter Academy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/learn-jmeter-for-free-launching-the-jmeter-academy) to quickly get ramped up on JMeter.

---

If you have to do it in C# from scratch it sounds like a test task or homework, therefore you landed into wrong place as StackOverflow is not code-writing service, you rather need an online freelancers marketplace.